# Passive motor control with resistance?

Tags: motor

I'm planning on making a small desk toy involving LEDs and a motor to turn a reflective element, and I just want to know if what I'm planning is safe or not.

I want to use a series resistor to limit current to the motor. I only need the motor to turn slowly (no exact RPM defined), and I don't need variable motor speed either.

I know that it's better to use a real motor controller (or at the very least PWM control), however everything else in the design is completely passive/dumb and I'd rather not introduce an Arduino just to run a motor at a slow speed.

Comment: How slow? The lowest speed you can achieve with voltage control is about 10% of rated speed. Below that, especially small DC motors tend to stick. With a series resistor, it's worse. Also, with a series resistor you are limiting the torque the motor can apply, so the speed heavily depends of the countertorque the mechanics of the toy applies, and it may vary extremely.

Comment: Which motor are you intending to use, what speed do you want, and what is the power supply?

Comment: I will likely be using a motor like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11696). I'd like it to rotate somewhere around 0.5 to 1.5 revolutions per second, and I was planning on using a 5V power rail. The speed isn't important, just has to be slow enough that it doesn't look like a rave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a series resistor to reduce the speed of a small DC motor by reducing the voltage, but the effectiveness of that will be very limited. You can probably reduce the speed to 20 percent of the normal speed. The speed will vary with load variation. If you want something less than a few revolutions per second, the speed must be reduced mechanically. You can buy a motor with a speed reduction gear attached. That is the best alternative to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a belt drive or gears to make it turn slower.

If that adds too much complexion for the application, you can use a diode instead of the resistor, so that the motor can draw more current in ramping up the speed. Resistor will have a higher voltage drop on higher currents. With a diode the current dependency is much smaller.